# Read a text file for a specific string and open msgbox if not found

Tags: excel, vba

How do I open a text file and look for a specific string?

I want that the string "productactivated=true" determines whether to display a message on the Userform telling the user to activate.

A few days ago I asked for help with opening a text file and doing some reading and writing, so I came up with this

```
Open "application.txt" For Output As #1
ClngLine = lngLine + 1
    Line Input #f, strLine
    If InStr(1, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Search string found in line " & lngLine, vbInformation
        blnFound = True
Close #1
```

Comment: Provided your code runs on a Windows platform, you might want to have a look at the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` as an alternative for handling txt files.

Comment: I've actually looked into that, but I;m quite confused as to how to use it and it's functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your solution two files will be used showing how to read and write to text files. The writing was added just to show you how to do it but does not seem to be needed for your solution per your question statement. For this solution purpose, all the files are in the same folder.

The first file is the file being read from. For the demo purpose, since not data was supplied it was created with the following data and named "**TextFile.txt**":

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line and has productactivated=true.
Third line lays here.
productactivated=true is found in line four.
```

The second file is the file being written to. For the demo purpose just to show how it is done, but per your question isn't needed, and named "**TextFile.txt**":

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line and has productactivated=true.
Third line lays here.
productactivated=true is found in line four.
```

The **VBA code**:

```
Sub search_file()
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
    Dim FSO, FileIn, FileOut, strSearch, strTmp

    'FileSystemObject also called as FSO, provides an easy object based model to access computer’s file system.
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Set FileIn to the file for reading the text into the program.
    Set FileIn = FSO.OpenTextFile("TextFile.txt", ForReading)
    'Set FileOut to the file for writing the text out from the program.
        'This was added just to show "how to" write to a file.
    Set FileOut = FSO.OpenTextFile("TextFileRecordsFound.txt", ForWriting, True)
    'Set the variable to the string of text you are looking for in the file you are reading into the program.
    strSearch = "productactivated=true"

    'Do this code until you reach the end of the file.
    Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream
        'Store the current line of text to search to work with into the variable.
        strTmp = FileIn.ReadLine
        'Determines whether to display a message
        '(Find out if the search text is in the line of text read in from the file.)
        If InStr(1, strTmp, strSearch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            'Display a message telling the user to activate.
            MsgBox strSearch & " was found in the line:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & strTmp, , "Activate"
            'Write the line of text to an external file, just to demo how to.
            FileOut.WriteLine strTmp
        End If
    Loop 'Repeat code inside Do Loop.

    'Close files.
    FileIn.Close
    FileOut.Close
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot of msgbox]

Comment: Why checking `If Len(strTmp) > 0` when `If InStr` will do the job?

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for catching that. I started with code from another project and missed it. The code is now updated.

Comment: Thank you very much @sunsetsurf for your code :) I have since changed this code over from the old stuff and it works perfectly :)

Comment: Now it's OK! 